# How to fix 'Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot remove headers after they are sent to the client' in Express with Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I wanted to use Express routes and wanted to use `index.ejs` in `views folder` instead of `index.html` in `public folder`

This is a Nodejs webapp using Firebase. I've tried to delete index.html in public folder. but it showed 404 error instead of showing index.ejs in views folder.

I googled my issue to solve it. But I failed on it.

here's my directory for my firebase website.

```
MYAPP
-.firebase
-bin
-node_modules
-public
  -index.html
-routes
  -index.js
-views
  -index.ejs
app.js
firebase.json
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites":[
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
module.exports = app;
```

index.js in routes folder

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I do Firebase serve on cmd, I get this error.

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot remove headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.removeHeader (_http_outgoing.js:528:11)
    at Responder.handleNotModified (C:\Users\1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\superstatic\lib\responder.js:138:12)
    at C:\Users\1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\superstatic\lib\responder.js:100:19
    at tryCatch (C:\Users\1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:525:12)
    at invokeCallback (C:\Users\1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:538:13)
    at publish (C:\Users\1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:508:7)
    at flush (C:\Users\1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:2415:5)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Aug/2019:03:40:21 +0000] "GET /__/firebase/init.js HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by myself.

the problem was that I didn't do firebase init functions on cmd after firebase init hosting.

When I put my project files into functions folder generated by Firebase init functions,
everything worked fine.